# Parameter transfer to URI in SOAP UI for a Rest Service

Tags: automated-tests, soapui, jira-rest-api, ready-api

I have two REST Services: GET and PATCH.

The GET Service has a JSON Response and from which I need to trasnfer a property named ***tripId***. 
Add that property value to the URL of the PATCH Request as a resouce, i.e., 
https://patchRequest.com/api/trips/{tripId}/

Can any one tell me how to do it in SOAP UI/ READY API.

I'm not able to do it. 
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the JSON you get in the first response? That would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: I've given you the answer to your question, In addition to the method I have posted you can also use groovy but that would depend on the JSON response from the first payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a customer property in the test case section ( or even in the project section )

[image]

- Add a **Property Transfer** test step and export the value to the holder that you created

[image]

- Finally, Call the value in your URI

[image]

Comment: @Mani - Did you try this ?